# A function to resolve letters in a number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a price converter, which uses a parser because the numbers can be formatted differently.

Let's say I got an array like this:

```js
const prices = ["1300", "0.232", "12k2", "123.45", "14923", "1k2", "2k20", "1k300", "12k320", "8k23" ];
```

Now I made a function for that to turn them into floats like  this:

```js
const makePriceFromString = (str) => {
  let _price = str.toLowerCase();
  if (_price.contains("k")) {
    _price = _price.replace("k", "");
    _price += "00";
  }
  return parseFloat(_price);
}
```

Then I loop through them like this:

```js
const result = prices.map(price => makePriceFromString(price));
/*
[ 
  1300.00, 
  0.232,
  12200.00,
  123.45,
  14923.00,
  1200.00,
  22000.00, <- Should be 2200.00 
  130000.00, <- Should be 1300.00
  1232000.00, <- Should be 12320.00
  82300.00 <- Should be 8230.00
]
```

As you can see the last two prices fail since there were multiple numbers behind the 'k'. I'm stuck on how I make my function  resolve this

Comment: since this representation with `k` is not standard you have to make your own converter, like you did. The way is correct imho, but what do you do with `2k20` for example? so you may dig a little bit deeper. Also, for working codes I recommend CodeReview instead of StackOverflow

Comment: @pergy Thanks, I updated the question with test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the `'k'` with dot and multiply by `1000`. This works better for values like

```
string   your app.   rpl. with dot
 1k2       1200          1200
 1k20     12000          1200
```

because of the position of `'k'` isntead of adding some zeroes at the end.

```js
const
    prices = ["1300", "0.232", "12k2", "123.45", "14923", "1k2", "1k20"],
    numbers = prices.map(s => s.includes('k') ? s.replace('k', '.') * 1000 : +s);

console.log(...numbers);
```

Comment: So instead of adding `"00"` you suggest to multiply by 1000. What's the _"better"_ part of that compared to OPs version?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of it within the Array.prototype.map( ) without using the makePriceFromString( ) helper function :

```js
const prices = ['1300', '0.232', '12k2', '123.45', '14923', '1k2'];

const result = prices.map(price => {
  if (price.includes('k')) {
    price = price.replace('k', '');
    price += '00';
  }
  return Number.parseFloat(price).toFixed(2);
});

console.log(result);
```